# Is it possible to modify the "alter procedure" template in SSMS?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

I know how to modify "`CREATE PROC`" templates in SSMS, and I wonder if I can modify the "`ALTER PROC`" template, which shows when I right-click on an existing stored procedure and click "Modify". When I click "Modify", a script "ALTER PROC ..." will be generated, I hope I can modify this so it can generate

```
IF EXISTS ()... DROP PROC ... CREATE PROC ...
```

instead of

```
ALTER PROC
```

Alternatively, if I can create a new template to achieve the same goal, that would be good too.

Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you prefer drop/create to alter?

Comment: @zespri, I have several production databases that are supposed to be in the same structure as dev database. But they don't. So I have to create a "drop and create" script and run them on all of those databases when a stored procedure is changed, I want to make sure stored procedures are created successfully no matter if they exist in the database or not. We don't have complex permission configuration, so I think this way is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is, but you can get pretty close to faking it. Create a snippet (in my version of SSMS, there's a Code Snippet Manager in the Tools menu) for the "if exists... drop" part. Now, script your procedure, insert your snippet at the top and you should be good to go.

I would be remiss if I didn't mention that dropping a procedure drops any explicit permissions that have been granted or denied on it. If you're doing this so that you get an idempotent script, I've adopted this idiom to avoid that problem:

```
if object_id('someSchema.yourProc') is not null
   set noexec on;
go
create procedure someSchema.yourProc
as
   print 'not yet implemented'
go
set noexec off;
go
alter procedure someSchema.yourProc as
begin
   -- your actual proc
end
```

Comment: snippet is a good idea. We don't have complex permission configuration, so it's ok to drop and create all the time.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, In modify option, you can directly modify or **alter prc** as

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_name]
  @paramater INT , .... other
AS
BEGIN
   .... statement
END
```

What the good thing in below option, is when you give to some one or deploy on server. Its good to give below type of statement.

Which first verefiy that Procedure exist or not, if exist then it first drop and then create.

```
IF EXISTS ()... DROP PROC ... CREATE PROC ...
```

Modify option means right-click and modify which directly give, alter option which is good for development purpose. You know while development like alter table or change sp parameter name. that also include when you give to someone with current sp.

While to give some one , good to drop and create with exist option, so third party easily execute without error.

Comment: What is "modify option" you are referring to on the first line of you answer?

Comment: Because while development you can not drop and create. Simply goto modify and execute it. Becuase you know everything and verify also. At deployment you don't know everything.

Comment: So what is the "modify option"?

Comment: It does not address changing SSMS templates at all. And changing SSMS templates is what the question is about.